# Вывод в цикле jinja нескольких параметров

Tags: python, html, django, jinja

Веду разработку на Django.
На страницу html данные для вывода передаются следующим образом:

```py
def page(request):
   data = {
          'name':['nameOne',
                  'nameTwo',
                  'nameThree',
                 ], 
          'id':['1',
                '2',
                '3',
               ]
          }
   return render(request, "mainpageapp/page.html", data)
```

Я хотел бы видеть ссылку с текстом name и значением id

```html
<a href="/{{id}}">{{name}}</a>
```

На данный момент я могу вывести только один элемент в цикле for

```
{% for el in name %}
   <a href="/{{el}}">{{el}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Есть ли возможность вывести в одном цикле for два элемента словаря? Или какой-то другой способ реализовать это?

Comment: Измените способ передачи данных, объединив name и id в один список с помощью функции zip

Comment: (и что-то я сомневаюсь в том, что у вас jinja)